# How to get property outside of class?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have a class:

```
export class MapApi {
  [reonMap]: Map;

constructor(container: HTMLElement, props: nMapProps = {}) {
    this[Map] = new Map(container, libraryUrl, props);
  }

}
```

How to get instance `this[Map]` of `new Map` outside class?

Comment: You can make get and set method to access that property and using instance of class you can access method

Comment: why you're not declaring `Map` in class like `reonMap`?

Comment: Why did you wrap `reonMap` in brackets in the property defintion? What do you intend by assigning `this[Map]` in the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript supports [`getters/setters`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#accessors) as a way of intercepting accesses to a member of an object. In your class, this can be implemented as follows:

```
export class MapApi {
    private _reonMap: Map;

    constructor(container: HTMLElement, props: nMapProps = {}) {
        this._reonMap = new Map(container, libraryUrl, props);
    }

    get reonMap(): Map {
      return this._reonMap;
    }
}
```

To access it outside of the `class`, do the following:

```
const mapApi = new MapApi(...);
const reonMap = mapApi.reonMap;
```

Comment: Sidenote: Having all your properties accessible and mutable via setters and getters makes them mute and you could almost just as well make the property public. In OOP, one should avoid having outside access to properties as much as possible.